# How Can I Split parseCsvResponse Content into the Way as Google Importing CSV with Separator Type Detect Automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function parseCsvResponse(csvString) {
    var retArray = [];
 
    var strLines = csvString.split(", ");
    var strLineLen = strLines.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < strLineLen; i++) {
        var line = strLines[i];
        if (line != '') {
            retArray.push(line.replace(/"/g, "").split(/;/));
            //replace ; with separator from your CSV file
     }
    }
 
    return retArray;
}
```

[This is the script that I use, and the result is like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JMgO.png)

And these are some field in my CSV content wen I open in WordPad : **"sid","Detail Order No.","Invoice Number","Date","Location","Name","Type","Status"**

What I want to do is like the result while using Google Sheet Import Function

[And the result is like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y15E7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about using `Utilities.parseCsv()`? I thought that when `Utilities.parseCsv()` is used, the CSV string value can be easily parsed. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function parseCsvResponse(csvString) {
  return Utilities.parseCsv(csvString).filter(r => r.every(c => c.toString()));
}
```

- From the script of `if (line != '') {}` in your script, I added `filter(r => r.every(c => c.toString()))`.
- When you want to set the delimiter, please modify to `return Utilities.parseCsv(csvString, ",").filter(r => r.every(c => c.toString()));`.

#### References:

- [parseCsv(csv)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv)
- [parseCsv(csv, delimiter)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv,-delimiter)

Comment: I had replaced the script as yours, but there is an error that **Exception: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells.** @Tanaike but I am quite sure that the CSV file is below the limit

Comment: @Nicholas O Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your error of `but there is an error that Exception: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells.`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Because when I tested my proposed script using a sample value of `csvString`, no error occurs. I deeply apologize for this situation. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Here is the link, [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TgCRdiDMTDwrth-tV1_YNQBLHm1K3iMexEDs0sGALgM/edit?usp=sharing) The CSV file that I downloaded has been manually imported to Sheet 2. For the script, I am not sure if you can see in Script Editor.

Comment: @Nicholas O Thank you for replying and adding the information. I could see your sample Spreadsheet. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation. So can I ask you about the detail flow for replicating your issue using your sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks for your following up. What I want to Do is retrieving a basic auth-protected CSV with Google Spreadsheets, Sheet 1 is the sheet I want to import data to. And Sheet 2 is a CSV file that I downloaded from the target website. Perhaps you can download it with UTF-8 format. Please do any testing in the spreadsheet if you need!

Comment: @Nicholas O Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your new question of `What I want to Do is retrieving a basic auth-protected CSV with Google Spreadsheets, Sheet 1 is the sheet I want to import data to.`. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it and I found the solution, I would like to tell you. So can you give me a time to do? I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your new issue soon. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: Yes for sure, perhaps you can reach me in email? @Tanaike